# why Seagate is bad harddrive?

Tags: hardware

I have read:

> DVDRW, USB and SSD drives will suffer a limited amount of write cycles
> Formatting an IDE or SATA drive will not have this as it is just
> another write cycle. Just stay away from Hitatchi(previous branded
> IBM) Maxtor and Seagate for hard drives!!

Why does Seagate have bad HDDs? Which ones are good?

Comment: This question is really old and the information causing the quiestion is even older. Maxtor as a brand no longer builds HDDs, Maxtor was bought by Seagate about 15 years ago. This usually happens when a brand gets a bad rumour from bad drives. This has happened to Connor, Maxtor and IBM. People will stop buying those brands as they have heard that some of them crash. Also Seagate disks might crash, but it hasn't happened often enough to give them a bad reputition. At the time of this writing Seagate is one of the oldest HDD brands.

Answer (score 1):

On the branding issue: I don't know who wrote that, but they have no idea what they're talking about. Please ignore them.

On the SSD vs HD: SSD have a limited number of write cycles, usually in the millions for each sector. New drives use automatic wear leveling, and you should never have to worry about it (realistically) unless you're using it in a heavily used or very long-lived sever. (USB drives can be lumped in with SSDs for the purposes of this discussion)

Answer (score 0):

Every brand of hard drive has the possibility of failing. I have had drives work fine for extended periods of time with all the brands you mentioned above, I have also had a few die. No hardware is perfect but there is no evidence backing up Seagate drives being worse than any other. I have an OLD UNIX server (1989) with Seagate drives still ticking along. Plus they started out making 5.25 inch HDD's they have been around for a long time, since the 70's, by no means a bad company.